# What is difference between disabled and stateless session management?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-web

What is difference between the following options:

```
http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
```

and

```
http.sessionManagement().disable()
```

?

Seems like in the first case SessionManagementFilter will be added and do nothing. While in the second case it will not be added at all. So, seems like it is better to always use the second option if you don't need sessions. But I'm not sure.

Comment: see: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session

Comment: @GelnYang Thanks, but I don't see anything about disabled session management there.

Answer (score 1):

Behaviour-wise I've noticed that, as you say, setting it as `STATELESS` adds a `SessionManagementConfigurer` to the `SecurityBuilder` and disabling it just adds `null` as the configurer.

This affects the `SessionAuthenticationStrategy`ies added when configuring security. For example, enabling CSRF protection will add a `CsrfAuthenticationStrategy` even for statless case but will not for disabled session management.

To sum up: disabling it will not execute session authentication strategies at all but enabling it will execute it on each authenticated request for a stateless scenario.

Hope it helps, this is based on personal experience (configuring, trial-error, debugging).